# How to define a non-square Legendre pseudospectral differentiation matrix?

Tags: numerical-analysis, spectral-method

I am going to discuss my reasons for wanting this first, as this may in fact not be what I am looking for.

My reason for asking this that I have finished writing a piece of code that solves, $-\nabla \cdot(a \nabla u) = f$ where $a$ is discontinuous, this is the result of the code

[image]

we can see oscillations about the line of discontinuity, so I have been told that I have to enrich the approximation. After some manipulation, the meat of the problem is dealing with this integral:

$$\int_{\Omega}a\nabla u \cdot \nabla v dx dy$$

On enriching my approximation.

$$u(x,y) = \sum_{i = 0}^N\sum_{j = 0}^Nu_{ij}h_i(x)h_j(y) + \sum_{k = 1}^N\sum_{l = 1}^N\alpha_{kl}\tilde{h_k(x)}\tilde{h_l(y)}\Phi(x,y)$$

On substituting this into the integral

$$\int_{\Omega}a\nabla u \cdot \nabla v dx dy $$
$$\approx w_s\sum_{n = 0}^N \sum_{i = 0}^N w_n h_i'(x_n)h_r'(x_n)u_{is}, \forall s\in[0,N]$$

$$+ w_r\sum_{m = 0}^N \sum_{j = 0}^N w_m h_j'(y_m)h_s'(y_m)u_{rj}, \forall r\in[0,N]$$

$$+ \color{red}{ w_s\sum_{n = 1}^{2N + 2} a_1(x_n,y_s)\sum_{k = 1}^{N-1} w_n \tilde{h_k}'(x_n)h_r'(x_n)\alpha_{ks}\Phi_{1,x}(x_n,y_s), \forall s\in[1,N]}$$

$$+ w_r\sum_{m = 0}^{2N + 2} a_1(x_r,y_m) \sum_{l = 0}^{N-1} w_m \tilde{h_l}'(y_m)h_s'(y_m)\alpha_{rl}\Phi_{1,y}(x_r,y_m), \forall r\in[1,N]$$

$$+ \color{red}{w_s\sum_{n = 1}^{2N + 2} a_2(x_n,y_s)\sum_{k = 1}^{N-1} w_n \tilde{h_k}'(x_n)h_r'(x_n)\alpha_{ks}\Phi_{2,x}(x_n,y_s), \forall s\in[1,N]}$$

$$+ w_r\sum_{m = 0}^{2N + 2} a_2(x_r,y_m) \sum_{l = 0}^{N-1} w_m \tilde{h_l}'(y_m)h_s'(y_m)\alpha_{rl}\Phi_{2,y}(x_r,y_m), \forall r\in[1,N] \textbf{(1)}$$

[How do I form the Chebyshev differentiation matrix in MATLAB?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/24470/21030)

The first answer in this link deals with the definition of the $h_i'(x_j)$ functions, or the construction of the square Legendre pseudospectral differentiation matrix. The $\tilde{h_i}'(x_j)$ have a slightly different definition.

$$h_i'(x) = \frac{(1-x^2)(L_N'(x))}{N(N+1)L_N'(x_i)(x - x_i)}$$
$$\tilde{h_i}'(x) = \frac{(1-x_i^2)(L_N'(x))}{N(N+1)L_N'(x_i)(x - x_i)}$$

The construction of the corresponding square Legendre pseudospectral differentiation matrix for each of the above is given in code as

```
N1=N+1;
cheb=cos(pi*(0:N)/N)';
unif=linspace(-1,1,N1)';

if N<3
    x=cheb;
else
    x=cheb+sin(pi*unif)./(4*N);
end

P=zeros(N1,N1);
%N1xN1 zero matrix
xold=2;
%eps= epsilon!
while max(abs(x-xold))>eps

    xold=x;   
    P(:,1)=1;
    P(:,2)=x;
    %set first collumn entries to 1 (P(:,1) = 1);
    %set second collumn entries to x (P(:,2) = x);
    % and so on, the collumns of this matrix are the legendre polynomials
    for k=2:N
        P(:,k+1)=( (2*k-1)*x.*P(:,k)-(k-1)*P(:,k-1) )/k;
        %%Bonnets formula ;)
    end
    % Roots of (1-x^2)L'_N
    x=xold-( x.*P(:,N1)-P(:,N) )./( N1*P(:,N1));
end

%---Legendre pseduspectral differentiation matrix------------page 124-----
% of the book 

x = -x;
D=zeros(N+1,N+1);
for k=1:N+1;
    for j=1:N+1;
        D(j,k)=P(j,N+1)/(P(k,N+1)*(x(j)-x(k)));
    end
    D(k,k)=0;    
end
D(1,1)=-N*(N+1)/4 ;           
D(N+1,N+1)=N*(N+1)/4; 

%------------------------------------------------------------------------
C1 = -(1-x(1:N1).^2);
C2 = N*N1.*P(:,N1);
C = C1+C2;
% L1 = P' L2 = P''...
% LN(i,N) is the Nth derivative of the Nth legendre polynomial at x(i)


% The last collumn in each is only really relevant.
%The coll's before will give a wierd result, this is easily fixed 
%but we dont use them so....


L1 = zeros(N1,N1);
L2 = zeros(N1,N1);
L3 = zeros(N1,N1);
L1(:,1) = 0;
L1(:,2) = 1;

for m = 2:N;
    for k = 1:N1;
        L1(k,m+1) = ((2*m + 1)*(P(k,m) + x(k)*L1(k,m)) - m*L1(k,m-1))/(m+1); 
    end
end
L1(1,N1) = N*N1/2;
L1(N1,N1) = (N*N1/2)*(-1)^(N-1);

L2(:,1) = 0;
L2(:,2) = 0; 
for m = 2:N;
    for k = 1:N1;
        L2(k,m+1) = ((2*m + 1).*(2*L1(k,m) + x(k).*L2(k,m)) - m.*L2(k,m-1))/(m+1); 
    end
end
L2(1,N1) = (N*N1 - 2)*(N*N1)^2/8;
L2(N1,N1) = (N*N1 - 2)*((N*N1)^2/8)*(-1)^N;

L3(:,1) = 0;
L3(:,2) = 0;
for m = 2:N;
    for k = 1:N1;
        L3(k,m+1) = ((2*m + 1).*(3*L2(k,m) + x(k).*L3(k,m)) - m.*L3(k,m-1))/(m+1); 
    end
end

L3(1,N1) = (N*N1 - 6)*L2(1,N1)/6;
L3(N1,N1) = ((N*N1 - 6)*L2(1,N1)/6)*(-1)^N;
%this is the matrix that corresponds to the derivatives of h tilde.
DT = zeros(N1,N1);
for l = 2:N;
    for k = 2:N;
        if(k == l)
            DT(l,k) = C(k)*(L3(k,N1)/2);
        else    
            DT(l,k) = C(k)*(L2(l,N1)/(x(l) - x(k)));
        end
    end
end
for k = 2:N;
    DT(1,k) = C(1)*((1 - x(k))*(L2(1,N1) - L1(1,N1))/(1-x(k))^2); 
    DT(N1,k) = C(N1)*((1 - x(k))*(L2(N1,N1) - L1(N1,N1))/(1-x(k))^2); 
end
```

The reason for the 4 extra terms is that I have split the region into two, either side of the discontinuity. According to my professor I have to use a technique called over-integration. I am going to need to define another D matrix such that is it a $(2N+2) \times (N+1)$ matrix and similarly for DT(ilde).

So my question is

> How do I form the non-square Legendre pseudospectral differentiation matrix?, if such a thing exists. If not, how do I deal with the over integration parts of the expression?

Comment: Apologies for not exactly answering your question, but have you considered using e.g. discontinuous Galerkin methods? They are specifically developed to deal with coefficient jumps and are quite simple to implement. If your objective is not the use of a specific method it may be simpler than enriching the standard space.

Comment: You might be interested to check your solution against a straight forward implementation within the [chebfun](http://www.chebfun.org) framework. In regard of  spectral methods I can also recommend the literature referenced there.

Comment: I got so stuck on this, I had given up. I think the main issue was that I cant seem to define the matrix described below in MATLAB. I will look through this though, thanks for the suggestion. I think the implementation of the D tilde matrix is also incorrect. Just a mess really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the purpose of solving a differential equation, the differentiation matrix *must* be square (and invertible). You have added additional degrees of freedom -- thus increasing the number of columns -- so you also need to add the same number of (independent) conditions by increasing the number of rows.

If you have selected your enriching functions properly, this can be done by using these functions as additional test functions, i.e., inserting
$$v_{N+k,N+l}(x,y) = \tilde h_k(x)\tilde h_l(y)\Phi(x,y)$$
and integrating.
Since LGL-pseudospectral methods use nodal basis functions based on quadrature points, this can be seen as adding more quadrature points for each element; in particular, since the enriching functions do not raise the maximal degree, more than you need for exact integration of each basis function. Hence, this is sometimes referred to as *over-integration*; see, e.g., [this reference](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021999115004301).

Comment: Just so I am clear before I attempt to code this. I have edited the question above to highlight two terms of expression $\textbf(1)$, so these two terms are $\int_{\Omega_2} \frac{\partial \sum_{k = 1}^N\sum_{l = 1}^N\alpha_{kl}\tilde{h_k(x)}\tilde{h_l(y)}\Phi(x,y)}{\partial x} \frac{\partial h_r(x) h_s(y)}{\partial x}$. they are split into two. So regarding the differentiation matrices we define two square differentiation matrices $DT_M$ $D_M$ each of size $(2N+2) \times (2N+2) $ and when programming the first red term $k,r \in [0,N+1]$ then in the second $k,r \in [N+1,2N+2]$?

Comment: No, you always need all terms when substituting $u$. Only for the test functions $v$ it suffices to fix all but one of the $u_{ij},\alpha_{kl}$ at $0$ (and the remaining one at $1$). I'd suggest not thinking of this as splitting the matrix, but just pretend you now have $2(N+1)$ basis functions instead of $N+1$.

Comment: I am sorry about this, I am trying to understand this. So I am correct in saying that I need to define a $(2N+2) \times  (2N+2)$ version of the differentiation matrix? ($D_{M = 2N+2}$)This I must have to evaluate $h'$ at $n\in[1,2N+2]$ points( the rows). from the ranges I have defined above I would only be using upto the $(N+1)th$ column of $D_{M}$. Would this be correct?

Comment: Yes, if you mean what I think you mean. In the end, you need to end up with a $(2N+2)\times (2N+2)$ matrix -- of which the upper left $(N+1)\times (N+1)$ block is your original, unenriched differentiation matrix. Evaluating the new basis functions at the old points gives you another $(N+1)\times (N+1)$ upper right block. Now you need a lower left (old basis function at new evaluation points) and a lower right (new basis functions at new points) block of the same size to complete the square.

Comment: I am confused what you mean by old points and new points. Really confused. So the matrix you described above is a matrix that contains the entries of $h'(x_n)$ and $\tilde{h}'(x_n)$? or are you describing the stiffness matrix? It has been a few days, I am sorry.

Comment: What is sounds like to me is that this matrix you describe, lets call it $D_M$ will have $D$(contains first derivatives of $h$ at $x_n$) as the upper left block and $DT$(contains first derivatives of $\tilde{h}$ at $x_n$) as the upper right and so on. It would help me out if you could explain the old point/new point thing.

Comment: That is correct, where the $x_n$ are the points where $h_n(x_n)=1$ (and 0 for $h_j$, $j\neq n$). The remaining two blocks consist of the derivatives of $h$ and $\tilde h$ evaluated at the points $\tilde x_n$ where $\tilde h_n(\tilde x_n)=1$ (and 0 for $\tilde h_j$, $j\neq n$, as well as all $h_j$).

Comment: The $x_n = \cos(\frac{\pi  i}{ N})$, this is going to sound incredibly dense, but what exactly are the  $\tilde{x}_n$?

Comment: Those are the interpolation points for $\tilde h_j$ -- they *are* interpolating polynomials, right? Otherwise you're no longer doing pseudospectral collocation, and the whole concept of "pseudospectral differentiation matrix" no longer makes sense. If your actual goal is solving an elliptic equation with jumping coefficients, I'd second @moyner's suggestion of forgetting about spectral collocation and going with a discontinuous Galerkin method.

Comment: Yes. I should have phrased the question better. Mathematically, how do $x_n$ and $\tilde{x}_n$ differ? That is where I was confused earlier at "new points/old points".

Comment: Well, they should be different, for a start. They also shouldn't be collinear, otherwise the extended matrix will be singular. Otherwise, it depends on how you want to choose the enriching functions.